# Sharepoint calculated field get number only

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, field, sharepoint-list

I have a SharePoint list with a field, Field A, holding values such as "Text-11" or "DifferentText-150" and I want a new calculated field, Field B, that only shows the numeric part of Field A (i.e. "11", "150").
The number can be between 1 and 9999 so I can´t take always the last 2 digits.

Does anyone have an idea how to realize that with the calculated field function of SharePoint?

Comment: Doesn't seem like a programming issue. Maybe you should use http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use several different functions to accomplish this.  Your primary function will be `MID` which will allow you to grab a part of the original text but then you will also need to use `SEARCH` for your starting point and `LEN` to get the correct number of characters.  Here are the steps for making your formula:

1. You will need the index of the first character in the number.  This can be achieved by finding the first character after the dash ('-').  Remember that indexes in SharePoint calculated fields start at 1 and *not* 0.

   `SEARCH("-",[Title],1)`
2. Next you need to get the length of the number part of your string.  This can be achieved by getting the length of the whole string and subtracting the index of the dash ('-').

   `LEN([Title]) - SEARCH("-",[Title],1)`
3. Finally you can get the number part of the string by using the `MID` function and passing in the index of the first character in the number (Part 1) and the length of the number part (Part 2).

   `MID([Title],SEARCH("-",[Title],1) + 1,LEN([Title]) - SEARCH("-",[Title],1))`

Note: `Title` is just the name of the test column that I used.